# WinApi get number of available bytes from a USB port?

Tags: c++, winapi, usb

Is there a way to check the number of bytes available from a USB device (printer in our case)?

We're using [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [ReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365747%28VS.85%29.aspx) for IO communications with our USB device, which works. But We can't figure out how much data is available without actually doing a read. We can't use [GetFileSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364955%28VS.85%29.aspx), as even the documentation says you can't use it for a :

> "nonseeking device such as a pipe or a communications device"...

So that doesn't work.  Any suggestions? Are we doing our USB I/O incorrectly? Is there a better way to Read/Write to USB?

Answer (score 3):

You first need to open up the port in asynchronous mode.  To do that, pass the flag `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` to `CreateFile`.  Then, when you call `ReadFile`, pass in a pointer to an [`OVERLAPPED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684342%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) structure.  This does an asynchronous read and immediately returns `ERROR_IO_PENDING` without blocking (or, if the OS already has the data buffered, you might get lucky and get a successful read -- be prepared to handle that case).

Once the asynchronous I/O has started, you can then periodically check if it has completed with [`GetOverlappedResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683209%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

This allows you to answer the question "are X bytes of data available?" for a particular value of X (the one passed to `ReadFile`).  95% of the time, that's good enough, since you're looking for data in a particular format.  The other 5% of the time, you'll need to add another layer of abstraction top, where you keep doing asynchronous reads and store the data in a buffer.

Note that asynchronous I/O is very tricky to get right, and there's a lot of edge cases to consider.  Carefully read all of the documentation for these functions to make sure your code is correct.

Comment: sorry, i should have stipulated in the question that this is on a windows mobile device, so the Overlapped async stuff won't work.

Comment: @OTisler: In that case, I think your best bet might be to create a separate thread and do a synchronous `ReadFile`, but I'm not familiar enough with Windows Mobile to know if there's a better option.

Comment: Thanks, that's how we're doing it now. I just wish there was another way beside doing an actual read...

Answer (score 0):

Can you use C#?  If so you can access the USB port using [System.IO.SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) class, and then set up a [DataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx) event handler for incoming data.  There is a [BytesToRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.bytestoread.aspx) property that tells you how much data is waiting to be read.

All of this must be available in native code, if I can find it I'll edit this.

EDIT: the best I can find for native is [ReadPrinter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162895%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) - I don't see how to check if data is there, this will block if it's not.

Comment: I could use C# (would actually prefer it!) But how do you access the USB port from the SerialPort class? What port name do you give it? I quickly tried it but it won't connect with the USB port name, and when I do SerialPort.GetPortNames() it only returns COM1, 3, 4,5, no USB...

Comment: @OTisler - yes I was wondering how the binding worked.  Still digging.

Comment: @OTisler - you are out of luck, in .Net 4 `SerialPort` names have to start with "COM" - http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/365891/system-io-serialport-portname-can-only-start-with-com